Pull Data from Slack Lists Using Python API?
I have very limited programming skills, but I was hoping to use the new Slack Lists function to store communal data that would be pulled by an external Python script. Does anyone know if it's possible to access and pull Lists via API yet?
Ultimately, what I'm looking to accomplish is use a List to associate someone's initials with their Slack account, so just match a value in the Initials column and return the associated value in the Username column. This is super doable with a local csv, but not super user friendly for my even less tech inclined coworkers nor safe from accidental tampering. This Lists function would be PERFECT, if only I had a script to get the data back out of it!
I'm not very good with Slack's API, so I'm not even sure where to start!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
